# TypeScript, React and Gulp.js - defining react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, gulp

I am trying to make a workflow, where I can write React modules using TypeScript and automatic compiling to JavaScript via Gulp.js. I am using TypeScript 1.6.2, gulp-react and gulp-typescript.

My `.tsx` file looks like this now:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/react/react.d.ts" />
import React = __React;
interface HelloWorldProps {
    name: string;
}

var HelloMessage = React.createClass<HelloWorldProps, any>({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});
React.render(<HelloMessage name="helloooo" />, document.getElementById('test'));
```

My problem is this line: `import React = __React;`

When I leave it out, I get the error

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'React'.`

when compiling `.tsx` to `.js` (but it still compiles to JSX, and I can use the output). When I put it in, I can compile without errors, but when I try to use the file inside the browser, I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: __React is not defined`, of course.

This is how my gulptask looks like:

```
gulp.task('gui-tsx', function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src(config.guiSrcPath + 'tsx/app.tsx')
        .pipe(ts({
            jsx: 'react'
        }));
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(config.guiSrcPath + 'jsx'));
});
```

Is there a workaround for this? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. First install the React global definition via [tsd](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/):

```
tsd install react-global
```

This will create a file, `react-global.d.ts`, in your `typings` directory, which you have to reference in you root component file (the path is relative, so adjust it to your needs):

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/react/react-global.d.ts" />
```

After that it compiles without errors.

Comment: Is there any similar solution when using `typings` instead of `tsd`?

Answer (score 2):

> where I can write react modules using typescript and automatic compiling to js via gulp

Highly recommend you don't use global modules. Instead compile with `--module commonjs` and embrace the react / webpack / nodejs ecosystem.

You can checkout an example application here : https://github.com/basarat/tsb/tree/master

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! What is the reason why I should not do that? Is this in case I want to load external libraries which I cannot require then and have to load them via script tag?

Comment: While I think this answer is the right way to go, there's too little explanation for me to be able to use it from the sample app mentioned. My modules are referencing `__React` for whatever reason while trying to copy the style from the sample.

Comment: I've run into issues following this advice as well mainly due to the __React global as well in so many of the react package declaration files.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441400/issues-installing-react-related-type-definitions-with-typings