# Issues installing react related type definitions with Typings

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Whenever I've tried to install any React related package type definitions such as `react-boostrap`, `fixed-data-table` or `react-router` I get the following types of errors when trying to build with `tsc`.

> typings/globals/react-bootstrap/index.d.ts(5,20): error TS2304: Cannot
>   find name '__React'. typings/globals/react-bootstrap/index.d.ts(5,20):
>   error TS2503: Cannot find namespace '__React'.

This may be related to having to pull these modules in as "global" declarations. Here is an example of the command I'm attempting to use to install react-boostrap.

```
> typings install dt~react-bootstrap --save --global
```

SIDE NOTE: I get the indication that the state of type definition tooling is in a big transionary state between DefinitelyTyped, Typings, and what looks like a new [Microsoft led initiative](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/) coming with TypeScript 2.0. Is there a reasonable way that a consumer of these definitions should be following to get more consistent success with the currently available tooling? Should I revert back to using `tsd` even though it is [supposed to be deprecated](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269) by `typings` until the typings tool/ecosystem is more mature to avoid these issues because as it stands the `dt~` and `--global` parameters do not seem to lead to the same success rate that  I was used to with `tsd` and I had only moved to `typings` in order to get access to some newer definitions that were not originally available on DefinitelyTyped.

**Followup:** It appears that the official TypeScript documentation recommends using the `typings` tool at the current time to load react related definitions from DefinitelyTyped... Maybe that's where I've gone wrong attempting to pull from typings registry if available and resorting to DefinitelyTyped when otherwise unavailable.